# movie clip within parent flash move stops entire movie

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop

I'm a bit new to Flash. As I was developing my movie, I introduced 3 layers of sequential animation that I decided I wanted to loop X times. So I copied the frames, created a new Movie Clip symbol, pasted the frames into it, then deleted the original on the stage and dragged this new clip as an instance (`my_animation`) in its place. All good so far. 
However, when I play the entire movie, `my_animation` looped indefinitely, so I added a stop() action into that movie clip. That worked - plays once. I then added the following as an action on the very last keyframe of the main scene to try and get my_animation to loop X times:

```
var i = 1;
for (i = 1;i < 5;i++)
{
    my_animation.play();
}
stop();
```

However, `my_animation` still only plays once. It does not appear to loop as I expect. I also tried replacing `my_anmiation.play()` with `gotoAndPlay(117)` where `117` is the frame containing the movie clip, but still the same.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
**UPDATE:** I added a `trace(i);` statement within the loop. In the Output tab, I see:

```
1
2
3
4
```

…etc. SO - `my_animation` is not firing within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you call my_animation.play(); with in "**for** loop" like that, it just calls 5 time consecutively and it just starts animation .

> if you call my_animation.play(); during animation of my_animation nothing
>   happens. it works if it has stopped...

. so you need to listen add callback for to understand that animation finished and you can start that animation again..

```
var animatedCount:int = 0;
my_animation.addFrameScript(my_animation.totalFrames-1, onMyAnimationEnds);
my_Animation.play();

function onMyAnimationEnds():void{
   animatedCount++;
   if(animatedCount < 5)
   {
      my_Animation.play();
   }
}
```

this will animate my_animation for 5 time...

Comment: Thanks. Your code resulted in the whole Scene 1 looping, so I added a `stop();` just before the first `my_animation.play();` call. This prevented Scene 1 from looping, and indeed - my_animation then started looping as I want. However, it continued to loop forever....

Comment: A little trial/error and I've fixed it by taking the `stop();` out of `my_animation` and adding a `my_animation.stop();` into your code as an `else my_animation.stop();`. Thanks